# Run Powershell command in Python (SyntaxError: invalid syntax)

Tags: python, powershell, cmd, download, subprocess

I'm trying to execute a code on the system that downloads a file from direct link to `%appdata%` dir on Windows.

**My code:**

```
def downloadfile():
    mycommand = "powershell -command "$cli = New-Object System.Net.WebClient;$cli.Headers['User-Agent'] = {};$cli.DownloadFile('https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=19LJ6Otr9p_stY5MLeEfRnA-jD8xXvK3m', '%appdata%\putty.exe')""
    down = subprocess.call(mycommand)



downloadfile()
```

**But I get this error:**

> File "searchmailfolder.py", line 4
>       mycommand = "powershell -command "$cli = New-Object System.Net.WebClient;$cli.Headers['User-Agent'] = 'myUserAgentString';$cli.DownloadFile('https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=19LJ6Otr9p_stY5MLeEfRnA-jD8xXvK3m', '%appdata%\putty.exe')""
>                                         ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what command line string you were trying to build, but most likely you just need to remove the extra `"` before the first `$`.

Comment: not working @Paxz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps.Import subprocess and sys. And then try something like this
"command = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe","user_command.ps1"],stdout=sys.stdout)
command.communicate()"
Try putting your code into the .ps1 file

Comment: any help here ??